# Weird behavior of PHPExcel lib

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have encountered weird behavior of PHPExcel lib (I have never used it before). I have code like this:

```
$inputFileName = 'excel.ods';
echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

I dont know what exactly toArray method does because I CAN'T FIND ANY DOCUMENTATION OF THIS THING. I think that the problem occurs when an excel file has some blank cells - they are not copied but next cell is wriiten in their places or something. Could someone provide me documentation to function toArray? (i think that something is wrong with that parameters).

Thank you in advance :)

PS: it is code from example

Comment: What print_r($sheetData) returns? May be its easily solved with this info.

Comment: The point is that cells that are displayed well in excel, in script are empty (it happens almost always to cells on borders (last in column))

Comment: Maybe this helps for toArray method, will not solve your problem thorught (except these cells have script, date): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583915/phpexcel-read-all-values-date-time-numbers-as-strings

Comment: Try setting 3rd argv to false? Its about formatting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toArray() takes the data from each cell in the worksheet and puts it in a PHP array

```
/**
 * Create array from worksheet
 *
 * @param    mixed      $nullValue            Value returned in the array entry
 *                                            if a cell doesn't exist
 * @param    boolean    $calculateFormulas    Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param    boolean    $formatData           Should formatting be applied to cell
 *                                            values?
 * @param    boolean    $returnCellRef        False - Return a simple array of
 *                                            rows and columns indexed by number
 *                                            counting from zero
 *                                            True - Return rows and columns
 *                                            indexed by their actual row and
 *                                            column IDs
 * @return array
 */
```

> The documentation for PHPExcel is in the folder /Documentation.
>   API docs are in /Documentation/API
>   Examples are in the folders /Tests and /Documentation/Examples

There is a bug in the current 1.7.7 release that can misalign cells read from ods files when there are blank cells in the worksheet. This bug has been fixed in the latest code on github.

Comment: I have converted the file into xls and now it is working. Thanks :)