# PHPExcel Read datetime as string using rangeToArray()

Tags: php, date, format, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel 1.7.7 to read excel file. I encounter a problem similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583915/phpexcel-read-all-values-date-time-numbers-as-strings)

To get all cell data, I am using rangeToArray() like below:

`$dataCr = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.'G'.$row, null, TRUE, TRUE, false);`

However, it didn't return the data in any expected format, such as "2011-01-14 16:15:00" or "2011-01-14" or "2011-02-25 16:15". Instead it returned something like "40599.677083333" or "40599".

I am sure I set both true for the following parameters when using rangeToArray():

`@param  boolean  $calculateFormulas  Should formulas be calculated?
@param  boolean  $formatData         Should formatting be applied to cell values?`

I also tried update PHPExcel to 1.7.8. didn't work either. Is there way can work around? The expected date could be in different formats as listed above.

Many thanks

Comment: There is definitely a date format style applied to those cells? You're not loading the workbook with setReadDataOnly(true)?

Comment: yes from excel I can see the format is "ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD tt:mm". and what does the second one mean?

Comment: The second question is related to an optional setting for PHPExcel readers to read only the raw data, and not to read any of the style settings

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is set to true /**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/ 
  $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

Comment: If you have the line $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); in your code, then PHPExcel has no way of identifying whether a cell contains a number or a date value: comment it out... or use the built-in date management functions to convert 40599.677083333 to 2011-01-14 16:15:00

Comment: I commnet it out $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); and now it returns something that makes sense, like "2/25/11 16:15" and "01-20-11". Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Comment: @MarkBaker you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner (user1310312) may do so too.. ( :